# SQL conditional insertion of data. SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is essentially a question about inserting data into one table dependent on information in another table. The db is implemented with sqlite3. I am a relatively new user of SQL.

I have two tables, CUSTOMERS and MISSING as shown below (spaces indicating NULL).

```
CUSTOMERS:
ID|V1|V2|V3
1|18|23|14
2| 7|  |11
4|  |14|
7|19|22|12

MISSING:
ID|V1|V2|V3
 2| N| Y| N
 3| Y| Y| Y
 4| Y| N| Y
 5| Y| Y| Y
 8| Y| Y| Y
```

Table MISSING indicates which customer IDs in table CUSTOMERS do not have values recorded for certain variables. So, for example, customer 2 is missing a value for variable V2 but not for V1 or V3. Similarly, customers 3, 5 and 8 are missing values for all three variables V1, V2, V3. Note that customer 6 does not exist, so there is no record in either CUSTOMERS or MISSING.

When a customer has incomplete missing data (i.e., where, as with customer 4, the value of only 2 or the three variables is missing) there is a already a record in table CUSTOMERS, and I don't want to make any change. But when a customer is missing values on all three variables (as with customers 3, 5 and 8), I'd like to add a record to CUSTOMERS with NULLs in V1, V2 and V3, so that the table appears as follows.

```
CUSTOMERS:
ID|V1|V2|V3
 1|18|23|14
 2| 7|  |11
 3|  |  |  
 4|  |14|
 5|  |  |  
 6|  |  |  
 7|19|22|12
 8|  |  |
```

I know how to select the IDs from MISSING that show that there is missing information for V1, V2 and V3 ... but how do I use that to make the desired changes to CUSTOMERS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into customers (id, v1, v2, v3)
    select m.id, null, null, null
    from missing m
    where m.v1 = 'Y' and m.v2 = 'Y' and m.v3 = 'Y';
```

That said, you should revise your data model.  The table `missing` is not needed; all the information is in `customers`.

Comment: Yes he should revise his approach, but no, not all the information he needs "is in CUSTOMERS" (first version he provided).  You can't decide from that one that rows [with ID] 3,5,8 should be there but row [with ID] 6 should not.

Comment: As I implied in my previous comment, I agree that the table MISSING is entirely unnecessary. The real issue is, given the two Excel worksheets that I mentioned in the comment, how does one end up with the final data model that one wants. For the sake of replication, it seemed sensible to import Tables 1 and 6 of the workbook that was provided as the initial tables in the database, and only then to create the methods for altering their structure. I appreciate both the comments about the model, and the solution (which has taken me a little while to understand) to the problem as posted.

Comment: The critical thing that I had not understood when I tried to solve the problem myself was that one can put constants as the nominal things to be "selected" (which they aren't really!) from the table, as in Linnof's SELECT m.id, null, null, null .

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are relatively new to SQL, I will start off by suggesting that you change your approach.  By having one table with data present, and another table with data missing, you are making this more complicated that it has to be.  I recommend just maintaining a single `CUSTOMERS` table with all customers present.  Then, if you want to find out if, e.g., a custom is missing data for `V2`, you may use the simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE V2 IS NULL;
```

This approach frees you from having to maintain a separate table which records what is missing.  If the data isn't present in `CUSTOMERS`, then you already know it's missing.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion, but the tables are not really of my creation. I'm constructing an SQLite database based on the Australian Bureau of Statistics Socio-Economic Indexes for Areas. In the spreadsheet at http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/subscriber.nsf/log?openagent&2033.0.55.001%20sa1%20indexes.xls&2033.0.55.001&Data%20Cubes&9828E2819C30D96DCA257B43000E923E&0&2011&05.04.2013&Latest my "Customers" table effectively corresponds to the "Table 1" worksheet, and "Missing" corresponds to the "Table 6" worksheet.  If I knew how to do what I asked, I'd have the kind of table you think I should!

Comment: If you are "constructing a ... database", then YES the tables ARE "of your creation".  Both the CUSTOMERS table and the MISSING table can be obtained as a view on the table Tim is suggesting here.

Comment: @ErwinSmout I was going to give a literal answer too, but it would be a lot of work and would involve generating a sequence.